# What finishes are compatible with HVLP spraying?

Tags: finishing

I am strongly considering purchasing an entry-level HVLP sprayer after seeing many people rave about how amazing of a finish you get when you spray vs. brush.

I'm curious whether there are certain finishes that are incompatible with spraying due to any number of factors.  Essentially, if I am starting out with a brand new HVLP spray gun, how do I not ruin it the first day?

Answer (score 3):

I use an Earlex 5500 HVLP sprayer.  It works well for most solvent based finishes (lacquer, shellac, varnish).  It will work for very thin latex paints, but the turbine really isn't powerful enough for regular use.  It comes with a viscosity tester to help you determine if it is thin enough.